# Mass check out SharePoint 2013 when copying to SharePoint 2010, retain Version History

Tags: 2013, workflow, version-history

I need to move most of the contents of our current SharePoint 2013 site, to a SharePoint 2010 site (due to Corporate merger). I have mapped the network drives so I can just drag and drop what we need, but I need to ensure Version History is kept, and that everything is Checked Out on the original SharePoint 2013 site. I'm a total novice - boss said look into workflows?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think workflows would be the best approach for this. Is there a reason why the documents need to be checked out? If it's to prevent other users from modifying the original documents, you might look at removing the ability for users to modify content instead. 
I haven't attempted with going backward in versions, but have a look at `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` PowerShell cmdlets. These commands will allow you to export document libraries including versions into a new library in the destination.

Exporting

```
Export-SPWeb http://site/subsite -IncludeVersions 4 (all versions) -ItemUrl "Shared Documents" -Path "C:\SharedDocuments.cmp"
```

Importing

```
Import-SPWeb http://newsite/newsubsite -Path "C:\SharedDocuments.cmp" -Force
```

Caveat: 'Shared Documents' must not exist in the destination using export/import.